# Grails Load r:require

Tags: grails

In my ApplicationResources.groovy I have

```
modules = {
    common {
        dependsOn('jquery')
        resource url: 'js/jquery.datetimepicker.js'
        resource url: 'css/jquery.datetimepicker.css'
    }
}
```

And my index.gps have this in the head

```
<r:require modules="common"/>
```

In my layout.gsp:

```
<r:layoutResources/>
```

But it's giving me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'` when I use

```
<script>
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

and another error is when I use  `It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]`:

```
<r:script>
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</r:script>
```

I'm confused about r:script vs script. Is there anything I'm missing? When I'm inspecting, only load the jquery and the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *two* separate instances of `<r:layoutResources/>` in your layout GSP, one just before the `</head>` and the other just before the `</body>`.  The first one will render resources with "head" disposition, the second will render those with "defer".

Since the `layoutResources` tags go at the end of the head/body, the resulting script tags or CSS links will appear after any plain `<script>` you define.  But `<r:script>` will queue up to be output by `<r:layoutResources/>` in the appropriate disposition, *after* it has rendered the resources requested by `<r:require>`.

Comment: Ohhh now I got it. I thought it didn't matter if using `<script>` and `<r:script>`.