# Grails r:require on modal

Tags: grails, gsp

So i read the requirements for using r:require tag in [Grails Load r:require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871555/grails-load-rrequire) are that,

- Requires 1st g:layoutResources before head closure
- Requires 2nd g:layoutResources before body closure

But i'm doing a modal on my GSP page and i need to use jqgrid resource defined on the applicationResources.groovy on it. And the modal has neither head nor body tag on it, only some g:set and div tags.

The jqgrid is defined inside the  tag inside the modal's gsp file. I tried to put the following

```
<r:require module='jqgrid' />
<r:layoutResources />
```

before and after the script tag, or outside of the div tags, but still not working.

So where should i define the r:require so that i can use jqgrid resource for my modal?

Comment: You should include the resources for the modal in the GSP page which has the modal. E.g. the parent page of the modal.

Comment: That's the thing i'm trying to solve. Because the modal is created using a modal plugin upon button clicking on _header.gsp. I tried to tweak the _header.gsp but still no result. I wonder if i can append the gsp tag dynamically using javascript onto the modal?

Comment: Don't include it in the template (_header.gsp) include it in the page (GSP) which you are launching the modal from. Think of it this way. A modal has resources that it needs to function, the GSP has modal on it. Those resources have to be present on that page to launch the modal.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get you. The button that launches the modal is located on the _header.gsp. From there, the modal is defined using javascript instead of GSP. GSP pages related to the modal is defined in the modal views but only for the contents of the modal. I tried putting the r:require on those gsp pages for modal contents but didn't work.

Comment: What page includes/uses _header.gsp? That's the page that needs to include the resources for the modal.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Most of the pages in my web app use the same _header.gsp. And since the modal button is located at the header page, so the modal can be accessed from every page that loads the same header page.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to consider adding the resources to your layout if almost all your pages include _header.gsp. My question wasn't really a specific one, but rather one to help guide you to the answer of what page/pages need to include the resources.